# How to get random array values, not just keys with php?

Tags: php, arrays, random

I am trying to create little app that randomly selects a number of chords/notes from a scale but I am having trouble with using the array_rand to get those random values from an array. 
I have an array called $scale that looks like this:

```
Array
(
  [0] => f#
  [1] => g#
  [2] => a#
  [3] => b
  [4] => c#
  [5] => d#
  [6] => f
)
```

I also have an array called $chord_amt:

```
$chord_amt = array(2,3,4,5,6);
```

I have used the array_rand function to randomly select one item from the array like so:

```
$selected_chord_amt = $chord_amt[array_rand($chord_amt)];
```

Now I want to output whatever number of random chords that this function can produce:

```
$random_chords = array_rand($scale, $selected_chord_amt);
```

The problem is, if I print this array, instead of seeing the chord/note values it just shows the keys like this example:

```
Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 4 )
```

How do I get the actual values, so the above output would look like this?

```
Array ( [0] => b [1] => c# )
```

Noob question, I know. Sorry.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation of PHP arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)? They are not that difficult to use. What about the [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) statement? They are designed to work together.

Comment: so frustrating when people post from `print_r` when they could use `var_export` and print a valid php array.  Sorry I'm to lazy to change it.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix, have you considered that not everyone knows everything about php?

Comment: @MylesMalloy - no I never considered that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using a different approach, actually. Using `array_rand` on this array

```
$chord_amt = array(2,3,4,5,6);
```

isn't really needed to generate a random number between 2 and 6. PHP has the `rand` function for that.

Consider the following instead:

```
// shuffle the list of chords
shuffle($scale);

// take a slice of it with a random length between 2 and 6
$random_chords = array_slice($scale, 0, rand(2, 6));
```

Comment: It's a good answer, however you will lose some granularity in your `$chord_amt` array, consider if it could be like this `$chord_amt = array(1,3,4,5,6);` with a value skipped ( in this case `2` ).  This may be acceptable but I just thought I would point that out, it's how my mind works.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix yeah, that's definitely a good point. This couldn't work for a set of values like that.

Comment: I wasn't sure as the answer that was accepted also suffers that flaw, but I don't know how important that aspect is, just that it was included as a separate array.  I have a knack for catching edge cases.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I suppose I was being a bit presumptuous about what the OP was trying to do with it. There could have been a valid reason not to use rand.

Comment: @Don'tPanic - lol, I don't know if I would go that far. Sometimes the simpler the answer the better, less confusing.  With these questions it's hard to say taken out of context of the wider application.

Answer (score 1):

Just introduce [`array_flip`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) with your `array_rand`:

```
$random_chords = array_rand(array_flip($scale), $selected_chord_amt);
```

Prints something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => f#
    [1] => c#
    [2] => d#
)
```

Comment: This suffers the same problem I mention in the other answer, as far as loss of the `$chord_amt` array and some loss of granularity, I see that as a control array.  But it may not really matter to the OP.

Comment: I guess you are talking on `array_flip`, if so, yes I did think too. But chords will be unique as per this scenario OP has!

Comment: I was meaning if a case could be where `$chord_amt = array(1,3,4,5,6);` with a missing value, I noticed that array didn't exactly match the one with the values in it. So it's possible some values are intentionally excluded. In the Question, values/keys `0` and `1` are missing from the array used to generate the random keys, so they are impossible to pull from the "master" array.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix this is chord amount and not the key. If it is `1` OP needs 1 random chord, if it is 3, 3 random chords and so on.

Comment: I won't argue my point, as it's pointless, but the fact remains this is in the original question. `I also have an array called $chord_amt: $chord_amt = array(2,3,4,5,6);`  ergo as I said pulling `0` and `1` the way the question is written is impossible.  In other words `$random_chords` could never contain those two keys.

Comment: Hmm. I guessed from the variable name :)

Comment: It's all good, it more then likely was a oversite/mistake in the original code.  Hard to say with no context, but I thought I would point it out, just to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
$intersect = array_intersect_key($scale, array_flip($random_chords));
```

Note, I didn't test this, because I'm too lazy to rewrite your arrays, but here's the documentation.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php

This is the question as I see it,

> How to get a set of items from one array with the keys based on the
>   values of another array

All random things aside, you have this array

```
Array
(
  [0] => f#
  [1] => g#
  [2] => a#
  [3] => b
  [4] => c#
  [5] => d#
  [6] => f
)
```

And then you want to get those values based on these keys

```
Array( 3,4 )
```

The answer being an array like this

```
Array('b','c#')
```